# Java filter images from an http response

Tags: java, sockets

Using [`Socket`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html) I can send http request to server and get the html response. My objective is to get each image may it be `png, jpeg, gif,` or any other image types.

However, by looking at the responses from different websites, I noticed that some images do not use html's `<img>` tag, and instead may be in CSS.
How can I extract both `<img>` images and css images (e.g. `background-image`)?
Is it good to use regex to get those images urls from `<img>`?

Please do not refer me to http classes like Apache HttpClient.
My problem is not on http protocol.

Comment: please provide basic code to clarify your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other answers have already mentioned, ideally you would use a tool that understands how to parse, render and recurse HTTP resources (i.e. .html/css/js/png/gif/jpg/etc).

That being said, if you were feeling particularly masochistic (and I suspect you are), you could do this yourself...

It's not a perfect solution, but if I was going to attack this with a blunt instrument, I'd use regular expressions (I won't go into the specifics of regex, it's already [widely documented on the interwebs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)). My process would be:

1. HTTP GET my base page.
2. Strip out all strings that match **your** definition of a "resource" (using regex).
3. Optionally recurse those resources, for more strings.

You've already mentioned that you can perform HTTP request/responses (using Sockets), so I won't cover that here.

Voila!

```java
/**
 * Regular expression to match file types  - .js/.css/.png/.jpg/.gif
 */
public static final Pattern resources = Pattern.compile("([^\"'\n({}]+\\.(js|css|png|jpg|gif))",
        Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE);

/**
 * Pulls out "resources" from the provided text.
 */
public static Set<String> findResources(URL url, String text) {
    Matcher matcher = resources.matcher(text);
    Set<String> resources = new HashSet<>();
    while (matcher.find()) {
        String resource = matcher.group(1);
        String urlStr = url.toString();
        int endIndex = urlStr.lastIndexOf("/") + 1;
        String parentPath = endIndex > 0 ? urlStr.substring(0, endIndex) : urlStr;
        String fqResource = resource.startsWith("//") ? url.getProtocol() + ":" + resource :
                resource.startsWith("http") ? resource
                        : resource.startsWith("/") ? getBaseUrl(url) + resource : parentPath + resource;
        if (fqResource.contains("?")) {
            fqResource = fqResource.substring(0, fqResource.indexOf("?"));
        }
        resources.add(fqResource);
    }
    return resources;
}
```

**The regular expression:** looks for well formed strings ending in `css/js/png/gif/jpg`

**The method:** retrieves all matching strings from the given text (aka 'http response'), tries to build a fully qualified URL, and returns a Set of the data.

I've uploaded a [full example here](https://gist.github.com/nickgrealy/bde1c63fc689f5c7b7725d86f1a61b81) (with sample output). Have fun!

Answer (score 4):

To get all images, including images loaded by css and perhaps js, you need more than the html code.
You need code that *understands* html and css and js.
You need a *full* browser.

Fortunately, Java comes with a browser. The [JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javase-clienttechnologies.htm) [WebEngine](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html).
Give it a url or html and it will load everything.
As WebKit, it knows the latest image loading technology, for example CSS [border-image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image).

We just need a way to get its images.
It does not provide [media list](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/page-info-window-view-technical-details-about-page#w_media), but since it is pure Java, we can hijack Java's URL handler to intercept its requests:

```java
import java.io.IOException; import java.net.URL; import java.net.URLConnection; import javafx.application.Application; import javafx.application.Platform; import javafx.concurrent.Worker; import  javafx.scene.Scene; import javafx.scene.web.WebView; import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class NetworkMonitor extends Application {

   private final String url = "http://www.google.com/";

   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      // Override default http/https handler.  Must do once only.
      URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory( protocol ->
         protocol.equals( "http" ) ? new HttpHandler() :
         protocol.equals( "https" ) ? new HttpsHandler() : null );
      // Launch as JavaFX app.  Required for WebView / WebEngine.
      launch( args );
   }

   @Override public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
      // Create webview and listen for ondone
      WebView v = new WebView();
      v.getEngine().getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener( ( prop, old, now ) -> {
         if ( now == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED || now == Worker.State.FAILED )
            Platform.exit(); } );
      // Showing GUI is easiest way to make sure ondone will be fired.
      primaryStage.setScene( new Scene( v ) );
      primaryStage.show();
      // Load the target url.
      v.getEngine().load( url );
   }

   // Your IDE should warn you about the sun package.
   private static class HttpHandler extends sun.net.www.protocol.http.Handler {
      @Override protected URLConnection openConnection(URL url) throws IOException {
         System.out.println( url ); // Capture url!
         return super.openConnection( url );
      }
   }

   // If there is no warning, you need to switch to a better IDE!
   private static class HttpsHandler extends sun.net.www.protocol.https.Handler {
      @Override protected URLConnection openConnection(URL url) throws IOException {
         System.out.println( url ); // Capture url!
         return super.openConnection( url );
      }
   }
}
```

Since you only asked how to get the url, this is what the code do.
The code can be expanded depending on your needs.

For example, two [decorator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) objects for the URLConnection should allow you to intercept getInputStream call and query its header (to determine mime type) and fork the stream (to save a copy of the image).

If this answer is useful, don't forget to vote up!

Answer (score -2):

You can use [JSoup](https://jsoup.org) a HTML & XML parser.
Here is an example how to do it,

```
String responseData = "";  // HTML data
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(responseData);
Elements images = doc.select("img");
// Elements pngImages = doc.select("img[src$=.png]");
// To parse specific image format in this case png
for(Element image : images){
   // Do what ever you wanted to do
}
```

[Here is related official documentation](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax).

Comment: This won't extract images used/loaded by CSS. I'd also use JSoup rather than regex: it's more reliable.